# Firestore C# - Update entire collection

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the Google.Cloud.Firestore client to try to update my whole collection with a single write when the user closes my console application. I'm not sure if that is possible, I know i can do that using batch but the documentation([link](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore/userguide.html)) doesn't have any batch usage example. This is my code so far:

```
private delegate bool ConsoleCtrlHandlerDelegate(int sig);

[DllImport("Kernel32")]
private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleCtrlHandlerDelegate handler, bool add);
static ConsoleCtrlHandlerDelegate _consoleCtrlHandler;


//the code below is inside the main function
_consoleCtrlHandler += s =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Application closed.");
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                QuerySnapshot allStations = await collection.SnapshotAsync();
                foreach (DocumentSnapshot document in allStations.Documents)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(document.Id);
                    DocumentReference doc = collection.Document(document.Id);
                    Dictionary<FieldPath, object> updatesRegular = new Dictionary<FieldPath, object>
                    {
                        { new FieldPath("status"), 0 }
                    };
                    await doc.UpdateAsync(updatesRegular);
                }
            }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            return false;
        };
        SetConsoleCtrlHandler(_consoleCtrlHandler, true);
```

The event is triggered but the updates have no effect.
Thanks